# How do I add environment variables to my React and Firebase project using dotenv?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, environment-variables, crud

I am working on a basic CRUD TODO list using React and Firebase. Everything works fine with the app, but when I want to use environment variables, the app cant load the history of todos that I previously added. It still runs as usual, but the when I refresh the page there seems to be no history of the TODOs I added. Furthermore, when I remove the environmental variables, and just use the credentials, the app brings up the previous history and works as it's supposed to.

These are the files. I already installed dotenv just to let you know.

firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";

require("dotenv").config();

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();


export default db;
```

app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Todo from "./Todo";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";

import db from "./firebase";
import firebase from "firebase";

require("dotenv").config();

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("todos")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setTodos(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, todo: doc.data().todo }))
        );
      });
  }, []); 

  const addToDo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    db.collection("todos").add({
      todo: inputs,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
    setInputs("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>

      <form>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel>Write a to do</InputLabel>
          <Input
            type="text"
            value={inputs}
            onChange={(event) => setInputs(event.target.value)}
          />
        </FormControl>
        <Button
          disabled={!inputs}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          type="submit"
          onClick={addToDo}
        >
          Add to do
        </Button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <Todo todo={todo} />
        ))}
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: From the code, I can't really tell the error but did you try logging the env variable to see if you are loading the env variables into the app?